# Is there a way to create a dynamic row numbering column with Angular and SyncFusion data grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, syncfusion

I am currently working on a data grid using **Angular and the GridComponent of SyncFusion**. I want to add a **dynamic row numbering column**. In the SyncFusion forum, I was told that there is no Built-In support for this kind of problem. So, I thought about asking here for ideas.

Some further information:
Right now, I am explicitly adding a column in the grid initialization that does the work in the beginning.

```
for(let i=0; i<myComponentConfig.componentData.gridData.length; i++){
      myComponentConfig.componentData.gridData[i].rowIndex = i;
}
```

-> myComponentConfig.componentData.gridData is the object-array that is getting binded to the grids dataSource

Now, the problem is that the grid has various functionalities that change the order of the row numbering.
Some of them , like adding or deleting rows directly change the grid datasource, which makes it relatively easy to react to these changes. But some only change the view on the grid, like filtering functionalities.

So, are there any possibilities to create such a dynamic row numbering, which reacts to row and column reordering, adding, deleting, filtering , ...?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have validated your query with provided the information and we presume that you want to dynamically to generate the order of row index  in the Grid dataSource property when reordering, filtering etc .. We have provided the CRUD actions(add / delete / Update) reflected to Grid dataSource since Grid dataSource order to bind on Grid UI. However filtering, searching, Grouping actions are perform in Grid UI with currentViewData basis that is not update to Grid's dataSource.

If we achieve this concern in the Grid, we cannot preserve row-index order in Grid’s dataSource when Filtering, Searching, Grouping, etc..

If we misunderstood your requirement, please share the below more details about your concern that will help to validate further.